# How can I dynamically retrieve files from MySql / Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm working on my CRUD app what I`m trying to do is to download files from MySql Nodejs server. Here the steps I've achieved so far:

- I create the below function to query MySql database to find the `id=179`(just a random id). The function is inside a file called userContoller.js.

```js
exports.readfile = (req, res) => {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id="179"', (err, rows) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.render('index', { rows, layout: 'main3' });

        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
    });
}
```

With Handlebars in another file called `index.hbs` I fetch the file with `{{this.profile_image}}`

```
{{#each rows}}


{{#if this.profile_image}}
<a href="{{this.profile_image}}" download>

    <img class="card__image" src="{{this.profile_image}}" loading="lazy" alt="User Profile">
    {{else}}
    <img class="card__image" src="/img/cert.png" loading="lazy" alt="User Profile">
</a>


{{/if}}
```

In another file `user.js` I placed the router for the `/index` page.

```js
router.get('/index', userController.readfile);
```

All work fine. What I want to do is to dynamically access the user id, instead of me inserting `'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id="179"'`. To achieve this I create the following function `exports.viewall`(also included in `userController.js`). `exports.viewall` function download the correct name of the file but instead to download the *.jpeg version download a USELESS *.html version and same with other type of file like *.pdf.

```js
exports.viewall = (req, res) => {
    //User the connection
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
        //when done with the connection, release it
        if (!err) {
            res.render('view-crew', { rows });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
        // console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
    });
}
```

How can I dynamically properly query the MySql/Nodejs server to download the file to my local machine?

for reference below I put the app.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const mysql = require('mysql');
// to be removed when deployed in heroku

require("dotenv").config();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');



// Parsing middleware
const app = express();

// default option
app.use(fileUpload());

//to load static file
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("upload"));
//Listen on port 5000
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //To parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)

app.use(express.json()); //To parse the incoming requests with JSON bodies
app.use(cookieParser());

app.engine("hbs", exphbs({ extname: ".hbs" }));//Templating engine to change the extenion of file from .handlebar to .hbs
app.set("view engine", "hbs");


//link which tell to the server express.js to get the routeing from user.js
// const routes = require('./server/routes/user');
app.use("/", require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));

// Connection Pool
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'nodejs-login'
  });
  
  
  
  
  
  
  app.post('', (req, res) => {
  let sampleFile;
  let uploadPath;
  
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }
  
  // name of the input is sampleFile
  sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
  uploadPath = __dirname + '/upload/' + sampleFile.name;
  
  console.log(sampleFile);
  
  // Use mv() to place file on the server
  sampleFile.mv(uploadPath, function (err) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
  
      connection.query('UPDATE user SET profile_image = ? WHERE id="179"', [sampleFile.name], (err, rows) => {
        if (!err) {
          res.redirect('/index');
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    });
  });



const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-thought the whole problem and here is the solution working for me:

1. On my front-end side I simply add `../upload/` in front of my handlebar link to database as per below code:

   ```
   <a href="../upload/{{this.profile_image}}">DOWNLOAD</a>
   ```

   In this way I re-route the the link to the folder where I keep all the file on my server.
2. I modify the router, so dynamically get the pic with the `/:pic` on client side request

   ```
   router.get('/upload/:pic', function (req, res) {
       var file = __dirname + '/../upload/' + req.params.pic;
       res.download(file);
   });
   ```
3. I left the controller as follows:

   ```
   exports.viewall = (req, res) => {

       connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
           if (!err) {
               res.render('view-crew', { rows });
           } else {
               console.log(err);
           }

           // console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
       });
   }
   ```

In this way, I create a download point as per front end code which downloads any file from the server taking the name reference from the MySql database:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use express dynamic routes. And pass a string variable for querying the sql database. like this

```
app.post('/:id', (req, res) =>{
const id = req.params.id.toString;
const queryString = `UPDATE user SET profile_image = ? WHERE id=${id}`

connection.query( queryString, 
[sampleFile.name], (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect('/index');
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Where I should insert the above script? I'm a beginner on node.js.

Comment: it's an example, you cannot insert this in your code you can learn how i'm doing this.